# Angularjs ng-bind-html not working with string start with '<'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to bind an expression using ng-bind-html , This expression can  contains string having html tag ("`<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>`") or simple string (name) , as I created here ,
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8940/

here , value of location can be any string, when location is location2 i.e  a string started with '<' , code is not working.

please help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it's trying to parse it into an html element, but there's no closing tag so nothing is shown. If you add a `>` to the end it will parse an element `<mumbai></mumbai>`

To actually show the character, use the encoded version `&lt;` so it won't try to parse it as an element.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8941/

Comment: Hi , Nice solution , but I really don't know , whether I get "<a href="www.delhi.com" >delhi</a>" or "<abdsc" , How can I identify when to convert "<" in &lt